# Why Wikipedia returns 301 response code with certain URL?

Tags: c#, wikipedia, dotnet-httpclient

Some  requests with special character in this with the french accents.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var data0 = await client.GetAsync("http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastère_d'Arkadi");
```

This simple code yields:

> StatusCode: 301, ReasonPhrase: 'Moved Permanently', Version: 1.1

Any ideas what is happening? Downloading the French article of New York works in fact. I´ve even try to encode the the name but nothing works.

Comment: very interesting. I have made a question out of it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33195267/17447

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia sends an HTTP 301 indicating that the permanent home of

> [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastère_d](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d)'Arkadi

is now

> https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d'Arkadi

If you look at the response header, you will see that the Location header has the updated URL.

[image: Response headers]

It succeeds in downloading the page in a browser because the browser automatically uses the new Location.

**UPDATE**

If I enter `https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d%27Arkadi` (the value in the Location header of the 301 response) in IE, I get an HTTP 200.  However, I also get an HTTP 301 using HttpClient.

If I use `WebClient`, I get the error "Too many redirections were attempted."  It looks like there is some sort of redirect loop happening here.  I'm exploring this further.

**UPDATE 2**

I downloaded the page [using wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), with verbose logging.  Note that wget was unable to validate the SSL certificate for Wikipedia, and that there were two redirects: From the http URL to the https URL, then again to the URL with escaped characters.

```
E:\Software\GnuWin32\bin>wget -v --no-check-certificate http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastère_d'Arkadi
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = E:\Software\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2015-10-17 23:22:43--  http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%E8re_d'Arkadi
Resolving fr.wikipedia.org... 208.80.154.224
Connecting to fr.wikipedia.org|208.80.154.224|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 TLS Redirect
Location: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%E8re_d'Arkadi [following]
--2015-10-17 23:22:44--  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%E8re_d'Arkadi
Connecting to fr.wikipedia.org|208.80.154.224|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify fr.wikipedia.org's certificate, issued by `/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Va
lidation CA - SHA256 - G2':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d%27Arkadi [following]
--2015-10-17 23:22:44--  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d%27Arkadi
Connecting to fr.wikipedia.org|208.80.154.224|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify fr.wikipedia.org's certificate, issued by `/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Va
lidation CA - SHA256 - G2':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `MonastA"re_d'Arkadi'

    [  <=>                                                                          ] 171,252      463K/s   in 0.4s

2015-10-17 23:22:45 (463 KB/s) - `MonastA"re_d'Arkadi' saved [171252]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I use the "Location" url provided, still yields 301 message using the HttpClient in c# maybe from the browser it works.

Comment: Should I suppose this is a bug in the HttpClient?