# Is it possible to set 301 in an infinite loop based on the request

Tags: http, redirect, language-agnostic

Please consider this language agnostic. I really like to know what happens beneath. The code is in C#. The problem is, I am trying to fetch this URL:
`https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d%27Arkadi` from code.
Whatever I do, I get either "MaximumAutoRedirects exceeded" or "operation
timed out".

Sample code in C#, although I see similar results in other languages:

```
var url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monast%C3%A8re_d%27Arkadi";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
try
{
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = Int32.MaxValue;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var res = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

My questions:

1. Why this auto re-direct is happening?
2. Is it possible to detect a get from code / browser? ( I don't know how to ask this. I meant that when accessing from Chrome I get the URL. But when performing a GET from code, I get infinite re-direct. So are those GETs any different was my question)

P.S: This question prompted me to ask this. [Why Wikipedia returns 301 response code with certain URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33190626/17447)

Comment: @ozgur: please read the question to understand why I have these tags

Comment: I've read the question, and I still think those tags are inappropriate. If it's language-agnostic, that means it's *not* specific to Java, C#, PHP, Python or Ruby.

Comment: Additionally, please don't "quote" (with `>`) things which are in no way quoted text. Now, what do you mean by "Is it possible to detect a get from code / browser?"?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't know how to get this question across to max audience. I am trying to get max reach with utilising `tab=interesting*. I will change the tags

Comment: That's abusing those tags. Don't do it. I've changed the tags already to more appropriate ones.

Comment: I've edited the question to say that you've seen similar results in other languages - I hope that's the case, given the tags you were using before. If it's not, please edit that part out of the question - or try with other languages.

Comment: ok. I won't abuse tags in future. and your edit is fine :)

Comment: @naveen you can't use tags to reach as maximum people as possible. They must be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set 301 in an infinite loop based on the request ?

Yes. An http server can send you an inifinite scheme. Usually the browser will detect an infinite redirection loop and will stop redirecting. A configuration problem on the server side **can** create a redirection loop. An HTTP client **should** be able to detect that and stop after a certain amount of redirections (and `request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = Int32.MaxValue` is maybe too big in that case)

Why is it happening? Well, mistakes. You can write rules in the HTTP server configuration with infinite redirections, the HTTP server is not a compiler, this will not be detected on the server side.

Or maybe you have a lot of different servers to manage and they do not all get the last configuration at the same time. In the wikipedia case it could be for example with someone *fixing* the redirections of a page. Say you have:

- A -> B
- B
- C -> B

And you fix it to:

- A
- B -> A
- C -> A

If any Reverse proxy cache as registered the `A -> B` redirection in a temporary cache, or if this is not immediatly available in all database replicas (as a wiki is storing a lot of rule in the application database), then... you could have both `A->B` and `B->A` responses on the client side.

> Why this auto re-direct is happening?

Because you wrote:

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

Note that I'm not a C# expert but it seems legit.

> Is it possible to detect a get from code / browser?

Not sure what you are asking for.

**EDIT**
Ok, so your question is how to track the HTTP traffic made by the browser when a *simple GET* is made, and maybe also how to track it from your code.

On the browser you have some native tools like the network tab in the development tools, where you can activate the `preserve log` button to track redirections, but for simple redirection I think you do not even need to preverve log to see the 302 responses followed by other requests.

If you want to catch all HTTP traffic on your computer you can always use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which is not so hard. Or you can enforce all your HTTP traffic in your application or browser through a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Thanks. I have elaborated my question to make you understand what I meant by, "Is it possible to detect a get from code / browser?"